# Events after FFmpeg in Cmd command is completed in C#

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, ffmpeg

I am creating windows form application using C# to manage cmd arguments of FFMPEG, also, I am using FileWatcher, my application as long as its running after clicking the button "start watching" is will watch if any new file landed in the folder, its will open CMD.exe and the argument will use FFMPEG to convert this Video file. its working but the issue is my C# application sends the command to cmd and thats it but I want to handle other tasks like if FFMPEG completed the task delete the original file ? how I can determine in my app thats CMD command completed and then start next task.  here is my cod

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"MY PATH";
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {


    }
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

         DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(InPath .Text );
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.*");
        string str = "";
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            str = str + file.Name;
        }

        var strout = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = @"/C ffmpeg.exe -i X.mp4 -Vcodec X Xout.mp4"; /// this is just argument example 
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);


    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would use to start a process and then wait for it's finished result

```
 Process ffmpegProcess = new Process();
                ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
                ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i X.mp4 - Vcodec X Xout.mp4";
                ffmpegProcess.Start();
                ffmpegProcess.WaitForExit();


            if (ffmpegProcess.ExitCode != 0)
            {
            }
```

Comment: Okay I got you, I didnt know that I can send the argument to FFMPEG directly and not using cmd.exe. Thanks I will try it and update you shortly. Thanks again :)

Comment: I tried and its exactly what I want, thanks a lot. just a small issue, CMD opens more than once (3 times) , the first one will do the converting, the second and the third will say the file (my output File) already exist do you want to over write? its strange why does it executes the command 3 times